# C - Random characters after using strncpy() function

Tags: c, null, integer, termination

I have the following program in C:

The main problem with the program is that after I perform the copy operation, a number of rubbish characters are displayed after the letters copied.  I know this is because the destination variable is NOT properly null-terminated.  However, if you inspect the code carefully, I am performing null-termination.  Why is the problem still there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strncpy` does not guarantee that your `destination` string will be null-terminated after the copy. My approach would be to:

```
destination[ nob ] = '\0';
```

Comment: It does guarantee that, but only if you pass the string length, and not the memory buffer length (which is always at least string length +1).

Comment: @Lundin: It is the other way around. If you pass the string length (the number of non-null characters in the string), only that many characters are copied (and they are all non-null). If you pass the buffer length and there is a null character in the source buffer, then the first null character is copied to the destination (and the following bytes in the destination are set to null too).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, that doesn't contradict what I said. What I meant is, if you have `char str1[3]` and `char str2[]="abc"` and then `strncpy(str1, str2, 3)`, then strncpy will not copy any null termination at all, but instead let your program crash.

Answer (score 8):

So, uh, how do you think `strlen()` computes the length of a string? Do you think *it* requires termination?

Hint: it does. An array of characters is not a string in C unless it's terminated by a 0-character. All `strlen()` does is count the number of characters until it finds the terminator, so using it in logic to terminate a buffer in order to make it a string is a chicken-egg kind of situation.

Your problem is that you are mis-using `strncpy()`. This is a very easy thing to do wrong, since the function is slightly nuts from a typical (beginner) C programmer's point of view. It simply doesn't do what you would expect it to, from the name.

You should probably just do this manually, as long as you're certain that `nob < sizeof destination - 1`:

```
memcpy(destination, source, nob);
destination[nob] = '\0';
```

Comment: @Matthew Feel free to accept this answer, if you feel it has helped you. Thanks.

Comment: I'd say strncpy is nuts from everyone's point of view. Aside from the null termination issue, it checks for null termination at every character, and it also appends an flood on null terminations after it is done with the actual copying. It is one of the more obscure functions in C.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, it's awful. I guess it made sense when programming using "records" back in the day, but perhaps no programmers from that era have survived, in which case I'd agree with you totally. :)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of:

```
destination[strlen(destination)] = '\0';
```

have:

```
destination[nob] = '\0';
```

`strlen` keeps reading until it finds the `'\0'` char.

Answer (score 5):

Matthew, when you already know the length of the string you are copying, you don't need `strcpy` or `strncpy` (which check each character looking for the \0 at the end). Instead you should use `memcpy` and then terminate the new string:

```
memcpy(destination, source, nob);
destination[nob] = '\0';
```

`memcpy` does not check for '\0' and so is faster.

Answer (score 1):

This will work great after some really small modification:

```
char destination[18] = {'\0'};
```

Comment: You are wrong! This will initialize table with all elements set to '\0'.

Comment: This won't help if the actual buffer length is passed to strncpy, which is the most common cause for this bug.

Comment: Could you explain why this will not help? To strncpy there is size passed which is checked to be less than buffer size 'if(nob > 17)'

Comment: @codewarrior In this particular case there is the boundary check, most often there is none, since most programmers are unaware of the obscure ways in which strncpy works. Even if you managed to dodge that risk, this particular case will then work like this: 1) Fill an empty space of 18 bytes with zeroes. 2) overwrite the zeroes with the actual data. 3) while overwriting the zeroes, check for null termination at every byte of the source string. 4) fill up the remaining buffer with zeroes (again). Very ineffective and pointless, all in all.

Comment: Had you used memcpy followed by setting a single byte to zero, you would get this: 1) fill the buffer with the actual data. 2) null terminate it. Done. No fiddling around with useless zeroes or additional checks.

Comment: @Lundin please note that char destination[18] = {'\0'}; will do exactly the same as char destination[18]; and then memset(&destination, '\0', 18); It means that all elements of the array will be '\0'. I will not have to null terminate it as it already is null-terminated. You will not have to look for useless zeros and even you will not have to think which element should be null-terminator.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use strncpy, it is plain dangerous. As we can see from your example, programmers always forget to input the correct parameters to it, and they get corrupt strings as a result. This is an incredibly common bug.

strcpy() is safer, but not ideal either, since it has no boundary check. If used incorrectly it could lead to buffer overflows, which is a security concern. This is also a common bug.

The fastest and safest way to copy strings is through memcpy:

```
memcpy(destination, source, nob);
desitnation[nob] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is failing because **strncpy** copies only the first **nob** characters and does not append a trailing **0**.  Your attempt to add a trailing 0 with the **strlen()** on the destination string does not help, because it count characters until the 1st 0, and put a zero in that location (which will have no effect).

One way to "hack" a fix would be to clear your destination string:

```
memset( destination, 0, sizeof(destination));
```

There are probably much better solutions, including making your test for **> 17** be **> 18**.

Comment: Your hack won't help if the actual buffer length is passed to strncpy, which is the most common cause of this bug. Because then the null termination cannot fit anywhere, so strncpy just skips it and merrily lets your program walk off into la-la land. C11 7.24.3 `If the array pointed to by s2 is a string that is shorter than n characters, null characters are appended to the copy in the array pointed to by s1, until n characters in all have been written.` But if the array is not shorter than n characters, tough luck, crash and burn.

Comment: point taken -- the memset() solution would not work if nob were allowed to be 18.